# Is there a collection of prime residue classes whose union covers all integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to create a collection $\{a_1(\bmod p_1), a_2(\bmod p_2), a_3(\bmod p_3), \ldots\}$ where $p_i$ is a distinct prime, such that their union covers all Integers? The size of the collection can be infinite. Intuitively it seems impossible but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: I suspect you mean for all the $p_i$ to be distinct, but you didn't say that.

Comment: Yeah, it meant to be distinct

Comment: Just for future reference, what would this topic be? If I wanted to learn more about this, what would I search for? Thank you.

Comment: Modular arithmetic in Number Theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to let $a_n=n$.${}$

Comment: Presumably you mean $a_n=p_n$ so the modulus is prime as requested.  It gets them all except $\pm 1$

Comment: No, this works regardless of the primes chosen to get all positive numbers since $n$ is covered by the $n$th  group. You could modify it by letting the a’s be $0,1,-1,2,-2...,n,-n,...$ if you want negative numbers as well.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to let $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $p_1=p_2=2$.